# Why does anchor appear before span

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the below markup and the `Preview` anchor appears before the file name.

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span>  </span>
  <span>file1</span>
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs col-xs-2" target="_tab" href="#">Preview</a>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/varungupta85/Luhcjs6r/5/

Could you explain why does the anchor appear before the span and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does the anchor appear before the span

That's because the bootstrap class `col-xs-2` has `float:left` which removes it from the normal document flow - *before* the span.

Regarding how to fix: One way: remove the `col-xs-2` class from the anchor.

or alternatively make your own class... something like:

```
a.btn-default.col-xs-2 {
   float: none;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Luhcjs6r/6/)